# When I center an ordered list the number goes to a separate line to the list

Tags: html, css

As stated in the title I `text-align`ed to center and used `list-style-position: inside` so that the number would go besides the list but instead it goes to a separate line.

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <h3>Gather ingredients and preheat oven:</h3>
    Preheat oven to 200 degrees. Have a baking sheet or heatproof platter ready to keep cooked pancakes warm in the oven.
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3>Mix dry ingredients:</h3>
    In a small bowl, whisk together flour, sugar, baking powder, and salt; set aside.
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3>Mix wet ingredients:</h3>
    In a medium bowl, whisk together milk, butter (or oil), and egg.
  </li>
</ol>
```

```
* {
  text-align: center;
}

ol {
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding: 0;
}
```

and the list becomes

[image]

I want it the number 1 and the header in the same line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `h3` heading is a block-level element. When `list-style-position: inside` is used, the list marker number is displayed as inline text. The `h3` block container is separate from the inline content before and after it.

```css
* {
  text-align: center;
}

ol {
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    inline text<h3>Gather ingredients and preheat oven:</h3>
    Preheat oven to 200 degrees
  </li>
</ol>
```

You can change the `h3` to `display: inline`. However, you'll need to put the additional text inside a block-level container such as `div` or `p`.

(Non-collapsing block margin will be rendered if you use `display: inline-block`, which doubles the margin between every `h3` and `p` container.)

```css
* {
  text-align: center;
}

ol {
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding: 0;
}

h3 {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <h3>Gather ingredients and preheat oven:</h3>
    <p>Preheat oven to 200 degrees. Have a baking sheet or heatproof platter ready to keep cooked pancakes warm in the oven.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3>Mix dry ingredients:</h3>
    <p>In a small bowl, whisk together flour, sugar, baking powder, and salt; set aside.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3>Mix wet ingredients:</h3>
    <p>In a medium bowl, whisk together milk, butter (or oil), and egg.</p>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Another way is to change `h3` to `display: list-item` and change `li` to `display: block`

```css
* {
  text-align: center;
}

ol {
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: block;
}

h3 {
  display: list-item;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <h3>Gather ingredients and preheat oven:</h3>
    Preheat oven to 200 degrees. Have a baking sheet or heatproof platter ready to keep cooked pancakes warm in the oven.
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3>Mix dry ingredients:</h3>
    In a small bowl, whisk together flour, sugar, baking powder, and salt; set aside.
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3>Mix wet ingredients:</h3>
    In a medium bowl, whisk together milk, butter (or oil), and egg.
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks for this comprehensive answer!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```css
* {
            text-align: center;
        }

        ol {
            list-style-position: inside;
            padding: 0;
        }
        ol h3{
            display: inline-block;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <ol>
        <li>
            <h3>Gather ingredients and preheat oven:</h3>
            <p>Preheat oven to 200 degrees. Have a baking sheet or heatproof platter ready to keep cooked pancakes warm in the oven.</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h3>Mix dry ingredients:</h3>
            <p>In a small bowl, whisk together flour, sugar, baking powder, and salt; set aside.</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h3>Mix wet ingredients:</h3>
            <p>In a medium bowl, whisk together milk, butter (or oil), and egg.</p>
        </li>
    </ol>
</body>

</html>
```

You will get this result
[Expected result]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaHg6.png

Comment: [I've been told to create a "runnable" example with "Stack Snippets". How do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: No, this alone will not get the result you pictured. The additional text will flow inline with the `h3` text.

Comment: I was added code snippet

Comment: Thanks this worked! Would it be possible for you to explain the portion you added?

Comment: The h3 is block elements. That's why h3 is separate from the inline content before and after h3.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use like this?

```css
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center">
  <h3>1. Gather ingredients and preheat oven:</h3>
  Preheat oven to 200 degrees. Have a baking sheet or heatproof platter ready to keep cooked pancakes warm in the oven.

  <h3>2. Mix dry ingredients:</h3>
  In a small bowl, whisk together flour, sugar, baking powder, and salt; set aside.

  <h3>3. Mix wet ingredients:</h3>
  In a medium bowl, whisk together milk, butter (or oil), and egg.
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm currently studying lists and it's behavior in regards to css

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here, `<li>` is being applied both for the heading and the text beneath the heading.

Remember, every headings in HTML are a **block level element** and texts that are without any tags are treated as i**nline-block element** unless you use certain tags such as, paragraph tag.

If the text was only inside of the list element then it would have worked as you expected. But since there is a block level element in between them, it is occupying the whole block for itself. Thus it resulted as separating the number and the text.

To solve this you have to make the heading element inline-block.

As [Hasti Kukadiya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19261627/hasti-kukadiya) proposed, the code should be this:

```css
ol {
  ...
  list-style-position: inside;
  ...
}
ol h3 {
  ...
  display: inline-block;
  ...
}
```

Comment: This is an insightful and helpful answer except for "list-style-position is no longer needed" I suggest you try that...

Comment: Oh, sorry. I thought that it wasn't needed. Thanks for reminding me <3